# Use rsync to copy all files except for certain filenames with a certain extension

Tags: command-line, bash, find, rsync, cp

I have two same-size flash cards, and I want to copy contents of one to the other based on the following rules:

1. I want all directories and subdirectories in place
2. I want to exclude files of type .FOO, .BAR, and .ZIM (all other files are copied)
3. *Bonus:* It'd be cool if it outputs the filenames as they are copied considering it will be copying ~8 GB of information

Could this be done with "find" somehow?

Answer (score 68, accepted):

This would be **significantly easier** using [rsync](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rsync) with its `--exclude` switch.

```
rsync -av --exclude='*.FOO' --exclude='*.BAR' --exclude='*.ZIM' /source /dest
```

The `-v` switch will provide verbose output on which files are being synchronised.

Comment: Little follow-up here: the copy finished and /src/* is now in /dest/src/*  How to use rsync to get /src/* in /dest/*?

Comment: Try `/source/ /dest`

Comment: This doesn't work. I am still seeing *.FOO files being copied over.

Comment: It is specified how you should give the path for `--exclude`. If you have problems with it, [check out this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/83403/136348).

Answer (score 2):

If you have large number of extensions to exclude you can make a file and write down all the extension or file to exclude and use only one exclude option to make it simple.

> rsync -ravz --exclude='./abc,txt'  /source /dest

It is always good to use z for compression and r option if you have to copy recursively.

Comment: It is not always good to use z for compression. Unless you are transferring over a network you know to be slow, compression will slow you down. Also, if you are transferring compressed files (e.g. jpeg, mp3, most video formats), or have a slow CPU, it'll just waste time.